# Passing reference to an object in a ContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

[image]

To pass a reference to managedObjectContext in my Main View Controller I have the following code in my App delegate and that works fine:

```
//Grab the Navigation Controller in front of the Main View Controller
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

//Grab Main View Controller out of the navigation controller at Position 0
SceneTwo *sceneTwo = (SceneTwo *) [[nav viewContollers]objectAtIndex:0];

//Pass the reference to managedObjectContext.  
sceneTwo.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Problem: I'd like to pass reference to managedObjectContext in the ContainerView inside Main View Controller (Scene 1) that has a navigation controller in front of it.  Please see the picture above.

What should be the code to grab the navigation controller of the containerView?
What should be the code to grab Scene 1 out of that navigation Controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because your main view controller uses container views, you could iterate through the views in the `childViewControllers` array in your main view controller. Looking at the diagram, it looks like the first one should be the nav controller you're after. The below could go in `MainViewController`.

```
UINavigationController *scene1Nav = (UINavigationController *)[[self childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

When you find the correct one, you'll be able to set the `managedObjectContext` for it.

An alternative (that may be less painful that iterating through all the child views and navigation controllers) could be to set the `managedObjectContext` of your scenes in the scenes themselves, with a reference to the app delegate - e.g., in `viewDidLoad` of the controllers that need the context. For this to work, `managedObjectContext` will need to be a property or getter method of your App Delegate.

```
self.managedObjectContext = [(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will try this later today and post my reply.  

I really like your alternative idea; however, I wanted I've heard that it's not a good practice to reference app delegate this way.  Is that true?

Comment: I believe that's a decision that you should make on a project by project basis. It of clouds the purpose of the app delegate by using to it do things that a AppDelegate object shouldn't be doing, but you're probably clouding that purpose anyway with setting up all the managed object contexts in the view controllers. Having your object query the app delegate for the MOC means that it can't be reused without change' as it's tied to that app delegate. That tying is typically bad design, but it's only a problem if you need a truly generic, reusable object. Most view controllers aren't though.